# Receiving RTCM Data via NTRIP but can't translate the machincode

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a python script that send and receives data from an ***NTRIP Server (RTK)***. 
But I don't know how to translate the machine code.

For example I get this:

> b'3E\r\n\xd3\x008?]\x0c\xe5^;\x834I\x0c\xa0\x01Hy\x00\nDh\x00Q\xf6\xc0\x19\x10&\x00\xc8~\xb0%\x83\xfd\x00\x19\x1f\xf8\x00\xc9\x00@\x06H\r\x01,@x\tb\x05@2\x10\x17\x19@\xbaU\xca\r\n'

I've tried to decode it with `ascii`, `utf8`, `latin1`.

```
pwd = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(username, password).encode('ascii'))
pwd = pwd.decode('ascii')

try:
    print("Header sending... \n")

header = \
    "GET /{} HTTP/1.1\r\n".format(mountpoint) + \
    "Host \r\n".format(server) + \
    "Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/2.0\r\n" + \
    "User-Agent: ntrip.py/0.1\r\n" + \
    "Connection: close\r\n" + \
    "Authorization: Basic {}\r\n\r\n".format(pwd)

dummyHeader = \
    "Ntrip-GGA: {}\r\n".format(dummyNMEA)

print(dummyHeader)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((server, int(port)))
s.send(header.encode('ascii'))

print("Waiting answer...\n")
data = s.recv(2048).decode('ascii')
print(data)
for i in range (0, 10):
    s.send(dummyHeader.encode('ascii'))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)

s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

RTCM is a binary format. It can not be decoded into text. You will need a binary parser if you want to read the messages in the stream. But the normal use case for RTK positioning is to pass the RTCM stream unmodified to your GNSS receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to learn "How RTK works"

RTCM can be used by an RTK algorithm(usually its found inside RTK supported GPS/GNSS receivers). RTK algorithm takes two input

1. Raw gnss data
2. RTCM data from a reference/base station

and output a corrected precise location data in NMEA or any other vendor specific format.

RTCM data need to be passed to a RTK enabled receiver without any modification, so don't try to read or decode that data just pass it.

Only case you need to decode RTCM data is if you want to analyse RTCM data e.g. see the type of messages received and check quality of data

I use similar software just to watch for RTCM 1005 which is transmitted from ublox-f9p only when the survey-in conditions are met(time duration and min deviation). SNIP has ability to decode RTCM that helps to debug in such conditions.