# How to decode RTCM data that is in bytes format?

Tags: python-3.x, gps

This question has been asked by in [Receiving RTCM Data via NTRIP but can't translate the machincode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57622483/receiving-rtcm-data-via-ntrip-but-cant-translate-the-machincode) but there is no answer.

I am currently trying to get an RTCM and NMEA output from my ZED-F9P receiver and transmit those 2 data via XBee to a robot with another receiver. The code below is where I read the serial port and extract the 2 data types;

```
       
        line = self.serial.readLine()
        #TODO Decode RTCM properly
        line_str = bytes(line).decode('latin-1', errors='ignore')

        print (line_str)

        if(line_str[4] == 'G'): # $GNGGA

            if(len(line_str) > 10): 

                #Translate NMEA data into readable data
                msg = pynmea2.parse(line_str)
                
                self.lat_deg = msg.latitude #msg is the object, latitude is the attribute
                self.lon_deg = msg.longitude #msg is the object, longitude is the attribute

                #Emit the signals (lat_deg & lon_deg) to the slot 
                self.gpsdata.emit(self.lat_deg, self.lon_deg) #send as a tuple

            else:
                pass
```

Without any decoding, the RTCM output is as follows;

`b'3E\r\n\xd3\x008?]\x0c\xe5^;\x834I\x0c\xa0\x01Hy\x00\nDh\x00Q\xf6\xc0\x19\x10&\x00\xc8~\xb0%\x83\xfd\x00\x19\x1f\xf8\x00\xc9\x00@\x06H\r\x01,@x\tb\x05@2\x10\x17\x19@\xbaU\xca\r\n'`

With `latin-1` as the decoder, the RTCM output is as follows;

```
Ó Là ííÖ
µb\ D  ä  ðÿÿÿÿ '¹)  $             ÿÿÿÿÿÿ v
                                           ß                     N  ¨'  lB>        ëñµb D              ÿÿÿÿÿÿ v
                                                                                                               ß¡Ã
```

I have tried different codecs like `latin-1`, `utf-8/16/32`, `ascii` and `ISO-8859-1` but all of them are unable to give me a readable output like with NMEA messages;

```
$GNGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*56

$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99,1*33

$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99,2*30

$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99,3*31
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably KernelSAT services for RTCM decoding might help: https://kernelsat.com/kss.php

Answer (score 2):

RCTM is not text format like NMEA, so you need to decode it in accordance with ***RTCM STANDART 10403.2***
But if you want to transmit RTCM data to another receiver you don't need to decode it, the second receiver will do it by itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try "gpsdecode" tool. If you are Debian based user you can install it with.

apt-get install gpsd-clients

You can pipe it !

Answer (score 0):

Generating NMEA from RTCM is useless although it can be done.

```
RTCM frombase + raw gnss from your receiver= precised location(NMEA/ubx/...)
```

I believe you have to read more about RTCM, RTCM data are correction messages which are used by RTK algorithms which are mostly built-in in most high end receivers and some low cost receivers too. Ublox f9p have the same. You just need to push the RTCM data **without any modification** into the module. You could check that by watching the message ubx-rxm-rtcm, after few seconds you will see float then fix if everything is ok.

If you want to build a software to analyse a RTCM source then it may be needed to parse each of them. With snip you can see RTCM message details.